# How to convert RasPi Python Code to JetsonNano compatible python code

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to create a stereo vision camera on my jetson nano with 2 raspi cameras. However, I can find a lot of information and code online regarding RasPi but not jetson nano. So for example let's say I have these 2 python programs, the first for starting both cameras on Jetson nano and the second for starting both cameras on RasPi. I'm quite new to all this, so it would be great to get some advice on how I could get started on this. Thanks!

Jetson (taken from JetsonHacks):

```
   # MIT License
# Copyright (c) 2019,2020 JetsonHacks
# See license
# A very simple code snippet
# Using two  CSI cameras (such as the Raspberry Pi Version 2) connected to a
# NVIDIA Jetson Nano Developer Kit (Rev B01) using OpenCV
# Drivers for the camera and OpenCV are included in the base image in JetPack 4.3+

# This script will open a window and place the camera stream from each camera in a window
# arranged horizontally.
# The camera streams are each read in their own thread, as when done sequentially there
# is a noticeable lag
# For better performance, the next step would be to experiment with having the window display
# in a separate thread

import cv2
import threading
import numpy as np

# gstreamer_pipeline returns a GStreamer pipeline for capturing from the CSI camera
# Flip the image by setting the flip_method (most common values: 0 and 2)
# display_width and display_height determine the size of each camera pane in the window on the screen

left_camera = None
right_camera = None


class CSI_Camera:

    def __init__ (self) :
        # Initialize instance variables
        # OpenCV video capture element
        self.video_capture = None
        # The last captured image from the camera
        self.frame = None
        self.grabbed = False
        # The thread where the video capture runs
        self.read_thread = None
        self.read_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.running = False


    def open(self, gstreamer_pipeline_string):
        try:
            self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(
                gstreamer_pipeline_string, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER
            )
            
        except RuntimeError:
            self.video_capture = None
            print("Unable to open camera")
            print("Pipeline: " + gstreamer_pipeline_string)
            return
        # Grab the first frame to start the video capturing
        self.grabbed, self.frame = self.video_capture.read()

    def start(self):
        if self.running:
            print('Video capturing is already running')
            return None
        # create a thread to read the camera image
        if self.video_capture != None:
            self.running=True
            self.read_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.updateCamera)
            self.read_thread.start()
        return self

    def stop(self):
        self.running=False
        self.read_thread.join()

    def updateCamera(self):
        # This is the thread to read images from the camera
        while self.running:
            try:
                grabbed, frame = self.video_capture.read()
                with self.read_lock:
                    self.grabbed=grabbed
                    self.frame=frame
            except RuntimeError:
                print("Could not read image from camera")
        # FIX ME - stop and cleanup thread
        # Something bad happened
        

    def read(self):
        with self.read_lock:
            frame = self.frame.copy()
            grabbed=self.grabbed
        return grabbed, frame

    def release(self):
        if self.video_capture != None:
            self.video_capture.release()
            self.video_capture = None
        # Now kill the thread
        if self.read_thread != None:
            self.read_thread.join()


# Currently there are setting frame rate on CSI Camera on Nano through gstreamer
# Here we directly select sensor_mode 3 (1280x720, 59.9999 fps)
def gstreamer_pipeline(
    sensor_id=0,
    sensor_mode=3,
    capture_width=1280,
    capture_height=720,
    display_width=1280,
    display_height=720,
    framerate=30,
    flip_method=0,
):
    return (
        "nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=%d sensor-mode=%d ! "
        "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), "
        "width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, "
        "format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! "
        "nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! "
        "video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! "
        "videoconvert ! "
        "video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink"
        % (
            sensor_id,
            sensor_mode,
            capture_width,
            capture_height,
            framerate,
            flip_method,
            display_width,
            display_height,
        )
    )


def start_cameras():
    left_camera = CSI_Camera()
    left_camera.open(
        gstreamer_pipeline(
            sensor_id=0,
            sensor_mode=3,
            flip_method=0,
            display_height=540,
            display_width=960,
        )
    )
    left_camera.start()

    right_camera = CSI_Camera()
    right_camera.open(
        gstreamer_pipeline(
            sensor_id=1,
            sensor_mode=3,
            flip_method=0,
            display_height=540,
            display_width=960,
        )
    )
    right_camera.start()

    cv2.namedWindow("CSI Cameras", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

    if (
        not left_camera.video_capture.isOpened()
        or not right_camera.video_capture.isOpened()
    ):
        # Cameras did not open, or no camera attached

        print("Unable to open any cameras")
        # TODO: Proper Cleanup
        SystemExit(0)

    while cv2.getWindowProperty("CSI Cameras", 0) >= 0 :
        
        _ , left_image=left_camera.read()
        _ , right_image=right_camera.read()
        camera_images = np.hstack((left_image, right_image))
        cv2.imshow("CSI Cameras", camera_images)

        # This also acts as
        keyCode = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
        # Stop the program on the ESC key
        if keyCode == 27:
            break

    left_camera.stop()
    left_camera.release()
    right_camera.stop()
    right_camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_cameras()
```

RasPi (from https://github.com/realizator/stereopi-tutorial/blob/master/1_test.py):

```
# Copyright (C) 2019 Eugene Pomazov, <stereopi.com>, virt2real team
#
# This file is part of StereoPi tutorial scripts.
#
# StereoPi tutorial is free software: you can redistribute it 
# and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the 
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# StereoPi tutorial is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with StereoPi tutorial.  
# If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Most of this code is updated version of 3dberry.org project by virt2real
# 
# Thanks to Adrian and http://pyimagesearch.com, as there are lot of
# code in this tutorial was taken from his lessons.
# 


import picamera
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime


# File for captured image
filename = './scenes/photo.png'

# Camera settimgs
cam_width = 1280
cam_height = 480

# Final image capture settings
scale_ratio = 0.5

# Camera resolution height must be dividable by 16, and width by 32
cam_width = int((cam_width+31)/32)*32
cam_height = int((cam_height+15)/16)*16
print ("Used camera resolution: "+str(cam_width)+" x "+str(cam_height))

# Buffer for captured image settings
img_width = int (cam_width * scale_ratio)
img_height = int (cam_height * scale_ratio)
capture = np.zeros((img_height, img_width, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
print ("Scaled image resolution: "+str(img_width)+" x "+str(img_height))

# Initialize the camera
camera = PiCamera(stereo_mode='side-by-side',stereo_decimate=False)
camera.resolution=(cam_width, cam_height)
camera.framerate = 20
camera.hflip = True


t2 = datetime.now()
counter = 0
avgtime = 0
# Capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(capture, format="bgra", use_video_port=True, resize=(img_width,img_height)):
    counter+=1
    t1 = datetime.now()
    timediff = t1-t2
    avgtime = avgtime + (timediff.total_seconds())
    cv2.imshow("pair", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    t2 = datetime.now()
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop and save last image
    if key == ord("q") :
        avgtime = avgtime/counter
        print ("Average time between frames: " + str(avgtime))
        print ("Average FPS: " + str(1/avgtime))
        if (os.path.isdir("./scenes")==False):
            os.makedirs("./scenes")
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
        break
```